# Python CGI Open file with absolute URL path

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, cgi

I'm writing a Python script that opens a file based on the URL (using .htaccess). I want to be able to open it using an absolute path relative to the servers DocumentRoot. With PHP I would do:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/path
```

Is there a similar function with CGI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, just use:

```
import os
os.environ['CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```